# why YOLO v3 Keras buggy?

Tags: keras, yolo, roboflow

I am running this colab from Roboflow: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ByRi9d6_Yzu0nrEKArmLMLuMaZjYfygO#scrollTo=WgHANbxqWJPa

The code should be as-is, but i get errors at the end...

I suspect a TF versioning issue, but how do i know which version of TF i should install instead?

It should use TF1:

> %tensorflow_version 1.x

But

> !python -c 'import keras;
> print(keras.**version**)'

returns: Using TensorFlow backend. 2.2.4

What am i doing wrong here? Unistall TF & reinstall which version?

Thanx
Fred

Comment: You did not say what the errors are, don't you think they are kind of important?

Comment: indeed! important ;)

ERROR: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'control_flow_ops'